# Basic Understanding between Laravel Echo, Socket io, Redis and Vue

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, redis, laravel-echo

I am trying to create a fully functional chat application. Right now I have a working Chat online where unlimited Users can subscribe to a channel. This was done via Socket io, Redis and Vue. (As well as Node js for the server), but then I came across laravel echo and I am trying to figure out, how this can play a role in my setup, and maybe make things easier. I mean I emit events with Vue and listen with Socket IO , am I right that Laravel Echo is taking over that part?

Any Help or Comments are appreciated. Even shared experience will be gladly read.

Comment: Are you currently using Laravel for your app?

Comment: yes i am using laravel 5.8